# Element cannot be found only trough Jenkins build

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with my Automated test,
My test is running without problems trough Eclipse.

But when i want to run this test on Jenkins, it always fail on the same line(on same selector).

> Running TestSuite Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 21173 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0,
>   Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 34.563 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
>   f(webdriver.Single_match_ticket)  Time elapsed: 33.86 sec  <<<
>   **FAILURE! org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:  Timed out after 19**
>   **seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector:**
>   **a[id='PopularOpener'] > span[tittle='All']** Build info: version:
>   '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b29de65b790abb01f3ac5f7ea2191c88a7', time:
>   '2016-01-29 11:11:26' System info: host: 'Ivan-HP', ip:
>   '192.168.221.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),
>   userDataDir=C:\Windows\TEMP\scoped_dir676_8604},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   hasTouchScreen=false, version=48.0.2564.97, platform=XP,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   634bd38ceca35f9fabe19d967ad5d847  at
>   webdriver.Single_match_ticket.f(Single_match_ticket.java:85)
>
> Results :
>
> Failed tests:    Single_match_ticket.f:85 » Timeout Timed out after 19
>   seconds waiting for elem...

Here is part of my code:

```js
public void f() throws Exception {

    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");



    // open Google Chrome




    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    // Maximize window
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 19);

    driver.navigate().to("TESTED SITE");

  
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']")));

    // Set values for username and pass
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']")).sendKeys("1testuser");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']")).sendKeys("testtest");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")));

    // Click on LogIn button
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userName']")));

    String Username = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userName']")).getText();

    String Username1 = "1testuser";

    if (!Username1.equals(Username)) {
      throw new Exception("You are not logged in");

    } else {

      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.logout-btn.balance.visible")));
      String Balance = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.logout-btn.balance.visible")).getText();

      String[] parts = Balance.split("\\.");
      String part1 = parts[0];

      String secondpart = "";

      if (part1.contains(",")) {

        secondpart = part1.replace(",", "");
      } else {
        secondpart = part1;

      }

      int BalanceInt = Integer.parseInt(secondpart);

      if (BalanceInt > 200) {

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
          .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[id='PopularOpener'] > span[title='All']")));

        driver.findElement((By.cssSelector("a[id='PopularOpener'] > span[title='All']"))).click();

        

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

Comment: Do you run the Jenkins test on the same OS and the same browser as your local machine?

Comment: Yes i'm running Jenkins test actually on same machine.

Answer (score 1):

the test fail on this line:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
      .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[id='PopularOpener'] > span[title='All']")));
```

try to select this element not by css as you do

```
By.cssSelector("a[id='PopularOpener'] > span[title='All']"
```

select it by something else for example id, name, xpath.

Comment: I already tried to select that element with some another selector, but i got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Or if it fails only through Jenkins, check the difference Your local machine from the machine you run the test through Jenkins. 
Check java version, chrome driver, OS version etc.

Comment: Jenkins is running locally on my machine. So the Java Version , Chrome driver etc. are the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue with JavascriptExecutor.

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("Categories.readPopular()");

This function works fine on J

Comment: Please note this means that your element is not visible on the real page. The JS executer will able work even with the elements that are not available on the page. from the test perspective this is not always good.

Comment: Elements are visible on the real page, but when i'm running with Jenkins they are not visible. Locally my test is working without problems. i don't know why those elements are not visible only when i'm running my test trough Jenkins.

So my solution is workaround. Please update me if you have some better solution. Thank You